# Magick.NET reduce gif file size

Tags: c#, compression, imagemagick, gif, magick.net

I am creating gifs using Magick.NET, but the file sizes are bigger than they should be.

```
            ImageMagick.MagickImageCollection col = new MagickImageCollection();

            col.Add(new ImageMagick.MagickImage("1.png"));
            col.Add(new ImageMagick.MagickImage("2.png"));

            for (int i = 0; i < col.Count; i++)
            {
                col[i].AnimationDelay = 0;
            }

            col.Write("test.gif");
```

I have tried setting the quality, transparency, format, and other options, but they either to do nothing or even increase the file size even more.
What method is there for reducing the file size or quality of the gif?

Comment: What makes you think they are bigger than they should be?

Comment: @DaveZych Using other methods, the quality is higher and the file size is lower than imagemagick's

Answer (score 5):

I have added a method named Optimize to the MagickImageCollection class. This should reduce the size of an animated gif. Feel free to post a message at the [discussion board](http://magick.codeplex.com/discussions) if you need more help.